# How do I update Rails object when object to update is only determined in the form itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm looking to update a record but not in the standard Rails way in a form on the same controller. My form works fine there. I have a form in a different controller/view called `Shoes`.

The problem I'm having is the record a user is updating isn't a static record that can be pulled from the url (I think that's how Rails pulls generically - I'm learning so please don't decimate me for this if I'm not completely right here).  When a user clicks an item to add/update to their `client_sub_folder`, the two `collection_select` options in the form allow the user to select which `client_folder` and `client_sub_folder` they are adding to and subsequently that will determine which `client_folder` and `client_sub_folder` the item they are adding will go to/update.

I'm using Devise for authentication on the `Designer` model.

How do I do this?

My error message: 
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :client_folder_id=>nil, :controller=>"client_sub_folders", :name_prefix=>"client_folder_"} missing required keys: [:client_folder_id, :id]`

I assume some JQuery magic is going to be needed here.

Models:

```
class Designer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_folders, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :client_sub_folders, through: :client_folders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_folders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_sub_folders  
end

class ClientFolder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :designer
    has_many :client_sub_folders, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_sub_folders
end

class ClientSubFolder < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client_folder
end
```

shoes/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([Designer.current_designer.client_folders,@sub_client_folder], url: client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_sub_folder), method: :patch) do |f|  %>

            <%= f.collection_select :client_folders, :client_folder_ids, Designer.current_designer.client_folders, :id, :client_name, {include_blank: true}, {id: "get-folder"} %>

            <%= f.grouped_collection_select :client_sub_folders, :client_sub_folder_ids, Designer.current_designer.client_folders.order(:client_name), :client_sub_folders, :client_name, :id, :room_name, {include_blank: true}, {id: "get-sub"} %>
            <%= f.submit %>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this is a form for the Designer, correct? Then the user clicks selects a client_folder from the select list. And you want the chosen client_folder to now be associated with this designer?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic Sorry if it's confusing.  The form is for the `sub_client_folder`.  The `client_folder` and `sub_client_folder` are already associated with the appropriate `designer` and `client_folder` respectively.  I just want to be able to update attributes in the `sub_client_folder`.

Comment: Then I would probably put this form in sub_client_folder#edit. Then rails will update the correct object.

Comment: @JeffZivkovic I can't for this project.  Need specifically for it to be accessed outside of sub_client_folder#edit.  Thanks though.

Comment: So you want to update attributes about the sub_client_folder, but those attributes are not offered within this form?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic exactly.  I'll add the attributes, but I just need to get the form to work first and right now I can't even get the page to load without an error.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing the point. But it sounds like you want the user to visit the page for the sub_client_folder. Once there, the user will update the attributes of that folder. Or do you mean that you will soon add the attribute options within THIS form, located on shoes/index.html.erb?